# How to find .fmt files using kpsewhich

Tags: kpsewhich

The normal method for checking where a TeX-related file is employs `kpsewhich`, for example

```
kpsewhich latex.ltx
```

and the command line returns something like

```
<installation root>/texlive/<year>/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
```

However, trying the same for a `.fmt` file gives no output. What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 14):

You need to tell `kpswhich` the binary which it should 'act like' to find format files. For example, for pdfTeX one might do

```
kpsewhich -engine=pdftex latex.fmt
```

to yield for example

```
<install root>/texlive/<year>/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt
```

or for any engine with

```
kpsewhich -engine=/ latex.fmt
```